# Ionic Build error : Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to build an apk from my ionic code and this error is shown by the android studio

[image]

The irony is that I've been using capacitor and error is about cordova
What do I do here

the complete code is here

https://github.com/SadafShafi/PhatooProgress

Comment: Your project structure is mixed between capacitor and cordova... maybe create a new project for capacitor and copy app folder to the new capacitor project and then reinstall the plugins used in the project.. I think this way in ur project structure is because the project was cordova then u changed it in later point to capacitor so conflict occurred when installing plugins...

Comment: @MostafaHarb I just created new app in capacitor and imported httpClient and tried to build the apk and same error happened and when I didnt use httpclient and built, it worked fine. But also I don't think httpclient is a thing of cordova, for it comes from angular

Comment: yes http is pure js so it shouldn't make any build errors, the most errors that could appear from it is when u open the app after installation but on build it shouldn't.... do u mean by httpclient the native advanced http plugin or its HttpClient the js one i mentioned above?

Comment: httpclient from capcitor and ionic

Comment: then it shouldn't do error.. maybe check if there is a new version for http client that should be implemented though i believe httpClient don't have native code but it is javascript xhr request...

Comment: wait i checked ur package json file, u are using `@ionic-native/http` .. and i saw u used http client and not the native library in ur project so just remove this package `@ionic-native/http` and build hopefully should no longer do error...